# Laravel trying to return a view when the form is submitted

Tags: methods, routes, laravel-5.4

I have a basic form which is supposed to log user in but for the beginning I want to just return a view as the form is submitted using a controller, any help is highly appreciated.
This is the form, I don't think there are much to seee about it but I post it anyway:

```
form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('login')}}" method="post">
<div class="form-group horseLoginForum">
    <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="username">

    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</div>
```

and the route it uses is right below:

```
Route::post('login','UserController@userLogIn')->name('login');
```

and finally this is the UserController function:

```
 function userLogIn(Request $request)
 {
 return view('news');
 }
```

> Laravel version 5.4

I do not get any errors.

This is my composer.json file. I tried a few things in there

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {!! Form::open(['url' => 'login']) !!}
<div class="form-group horseLoginForum">
<input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="username">
  <br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
```

```
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

try this .Hope this will help

Comment: Form and Html package is removed from core components of Laravel as of version 5.4.

Comment: Oh, how am I supposed to pass data ftom html into controllor than?

Comment: Always need to say form open and form close ?

Comment: run these command 
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: from Request you can retrieve data in controller

Comment: so I run the commands you said. it still throws the error form not founded, I checked (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) it has this command **composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"** I tried to run it doesn't work, composer throws content-Length missmatch error. and when I try to add **      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,** it still gives an error

Comment: @Abhishek I added it to the question, and btw I tried some stuff in there

Comment: and sry for the mess, I marked it as code but for some reason it didn't work. now I made it code again

Comment: I don't get it why did they even remove Form and Html? what was on their mind. every single time I decide to use Laravel they throw a bunch of new shit at my face that I porbably have never heard of.

Answer (score 0):

```
"require": {
   "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
},
```

Add this in composer.json file
 then composer update